# c++ (C::B) error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c++, mingw, codeblocks

After compiling code, if I decide to change something in it, after the next attempt to compile I get this error. I've also noticed that in the Debug folder of my project, there is an .exe that can never be opened. Apparently this is causing the issue: I can't compile again until this .exe magically just disappears. I can't delete it, move it, anything. Then it just disappears. When it disappeaars, I can compile the code again. Why this is so frustrating is because it can take up to a minute, and I don't intend to wait minutes between each compilation. Coudl there be a solution? Thanks! (also if I can provide any other kind of information, like screenshots of something, just tell in the comments)

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: does your program shut down correctly - linking will fail if the program is still running

Comment: Try disabling your antivirus software.

Comment: it runs, i press a button to exit, then after i make changes i can't compile again.

Comment: *"i press a button to exit"* Which button?

Comment: disablinng antivirus didn't help either.

Comment: when i compile, my code it runs and says "process returned 0... press any key to continue." i press any button to make the window disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Your exe-file is locked. Have a look at the taskmanager whether the program is still executing. Another reason might be the "Appinfo"-service not running.

Comment: If I extend code::blocks in taskmanager, it only has itself listed. Another interesting thing is, if I don't edit the code, it compiles just fine. As soon as I change something it return this error.

Comment: @BalázsCsendes "if I don't edit the code, it compiles just fine" - I'd say question updates go in the question; but this doesn't actually add anything, since if there are no updates, the compiler won't have to write to the file, meaning that even if it's locked it will succeed.

Comment: Yes, I only realised afterwards what I have written.

Answer (score 0):

Something interesting has managed to solve my issue. If I dont't compile with the F9 button, but the compile icon, it works every time. I'm totally lost at this point, but at least my issue is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Task Manager and see if the Command Prompt Window is still running or not. If it is running, end it right there.

This happens with me too and the problem is always that the command shell is always active.

Hope it works. :-)

UPD1: Refer my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/61833417/8385813 . You're welcome. :-)