# how to Fix "Permission denied collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status" in Sublime Text 3 on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, sublimetext3

so, in sublime text 3, im program a .cpp file, and i'm compiler and there are have :

```
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file C:\Users\okera\Desktop\CRUD/main.exe: Permission denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[Finished in 0.8s]
```

Comment: Well, does your current user have permissions for that directory?

Comment: Are you by any chance running a build system that compiles, links and runs an executable while at the same time trying to run a program that asks the user for input?

Comment: Maybe your program is still running from the last time you executed it. Or your antivirus has it open.

Answer (score 7):

**This answer is provided with reference to Sublime editor 3 on Windows 10.**

The answer to this is that the .exe file is still running in the background which is why you do not have the access to run it again.

There is a simple fix as per my experience.

Step 1: Open Task Manager

Step 2: Open Details Tab ( This is just a sample to show where to go )

[image]

Step 3: In your case the the program you want to find in the "Name" Section is **main.exe**.

Step 4: Once you find it, click on it and click End Task at the bottom right of the Task Manager window.

Step 5: Now, your program has ended its run. Go to Sublime and build your code again.

Your code will run for sure.

Do let me know if any error is still occurring.
Thanks.